# Python 2.7: How can I pass in arguments such as 'café' from the shell and not get 'cafÚ'?

Tags: python, shell, encoding, arguments, diacritics

I've a programm that gets an argument from the shell. This argument will be the query used in a search operation.

If I pass in English words (i.e. no accents, etc.), it works fine. Nevertheless, if I pass in,  namely, 'café', I get 'cafú' (`print sys.argv[1]` results in `cafÚ` instead of `café`).

I thought I could solve the problem by converting it into a Unicode object, but I was wrong.

```
Q = unicode(sys.argv[1], encoding=sys.stdin.encoding)
```

I still get 'cafÚ'!! I'm going crazy...

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong encoding? Could you show what you get as `sys.argv[1]`, and the resulting unicode?

Comment: print Q results in cafú.

Comment: print type(Q) gives <type 'unicode'>

Comment: What system are you running the code on?

Comment: what is your shell encoding? I mean, the terminal?

Comment: Windows 7 and cp850 (print sys.stdin.encoding gives cp850)

Comment: You didn't understand what I mean. I meant to show the result of `print repr(sys.argv[1])` and `print repr(Q)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, sorry. `'caf\xe9'` and `u'caf\xe9'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet you're on Windows, right?

```
>>> a = "café"
>>> a
'caf\x82'
>>> print a
café
>>> a.decode("cp850")                      # DOS codepage 850 --> Unicode
u'caf\xe9'
>>> a.decode("cp850").encode("cp1252")     # DOS 850 --> Unicode --> Windows 1252
'caf\xe9'                                  # identical to Unicode codepoint
>>> print a.decode("cp850").encode("cp1252") # Display a cp1252 string in cp850
cafÚ
```

Use `encoding="cp1252"` instead, then it should work.

**Explanation:** (with some guesswork)

- `cmd` windows use `cp850` as their default codepage. This is evident from the second line in my session above, `0x82` is `é` in `cp850`.
- It appears that Python programs started under Windows use `cp1252` as their standard encoding, shown by the last line of the session above: `é` is `0xe9` in `cp1252` (like in Unicode).
- This is also evident when you write this string to a file (which by default uses `cp1252`):
  If I do `f.write(a)`, I get `caf,` as the contents of my file because `,` is `0x82` in `cp1252`).
  If I do `f.write(a.decode("cp850").encode("cp1252"))`, I get `café`.

Moral: Find out the correct encodings in your environment, convert everything to Unicode as soon as possible, work with it, then convert back to the encoding you need. If you're outputting into an interactive window, use `cp850`, if you're outputting into a file, use `cp1252`.

Or switch to Python 3 which makes all of this much easier.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, thanks! But I don't know why it works. Tomorrow, I may be using another pc and get all wrong. =( Might you please give an explanation? Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I tried to have my terminal using UTF-8 (http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8), but when I switched on my laptop, Windows wouldn't start. I had to go back to a restore point!

Comment: @user1669007: I have tried to give an explanation. Windows codepages confuse the hell out of me, though...

Comment: @user1669007 Can you confirm which solution you tried? I can see a warning in the post that the first solution (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP`) may make the system unable to boot.

Comment: @dkim: I tried the first one. Yesterday, I also tried the second method, but it only changed the encoding of Windows cmd. It's OK though.